# My betta is acting strange, loss of appetite and won't eat pellets!

Tags: behavior, aquarium, fish, feeding, betta

I got a halfmoon male betta fish a few months ago. He is in a two gallon tank, water exchanges happen 30% every week, I use water conditioner and keep a somewhat regular feeding schedule and he also has a snail for a friend. When I went to feed him today I noticed that he didnt come to me like he normally does. I then put out a few pellets that I use as treats and he put them in his mouth and spit them back out. I literally spent an hour this morning trying to figure out what's wrong and I'm at a loss. I don't think he has fin rot but I'm not quite sure. Im also going to do a full clean of the tank today to see if that helps! Any suggestions??[image]

Comment: I can tell that besides some minor tears in dorsal fin it looks quite right, he has beautiful, bright, vibrant overall color which is a general sign of good health but could also be deceiving. Do you think any chance could be that some small insect just fell into his tank and satisfied his hunger after being eaten as a whole? How is he today, how has his behavior changed since?